# Are observing all anniversaries disallowed in Islam?

Tags: practical-islam

From previous experiences, I understand that

1. Celebrating Birthdays is considered Makruh by many scholars
2. Mourning the death of someone should be restricted to three days except for the closest relatives of the deceased

But what is the ijtehad on

1. Mourning the passing away of very religious person like the grandsons of Prophet Muhammad
2. Observing "Urs" and holding food festivals in tombs and shrines
3. Celebrating personal events like wedding anniversary or some other happy occasion

If possible, a daleel from the Quran and Hadith would be highly appreciated.